# Unitary groups and special unitary groups

Tags: group-theory, complex-numbers, quaternions, symmetry, unitary-matrices

I'm trying to learn about group theory (I'm neofite in this field) for physics reading a book, "Physics from symmetry" by Schwichtenberg. In section 3.2 the author introduces rotations in two dimensions and talks about the $SO(2)$, then examines rotation using complex numbers and introduces the $U(1)$ group.

Then the author introduces rotation in 3 dimensions using matrices, thus introducing the group $SO(3)$, and quaternions, thus introducing the group $SU(2)$. Here the question is about the $SU(2)$ group. Reading online, I think it is correct to say that $SU(2)$ is a subgroup of $U(2)$, which is the group of 2x2 unitary matrices.

From this point of view the 2 makes sense, since quaternions can be represented using 2x2 matrices, but on the other hand, unit quaternions have 3 degrees (fixing the length) of freedom, not 2.

I understand that in order to avoid reflections it is necessary to define a *special* unitary group, but why for common complex numbers there is no such thing as a $SU(1)$ group? And moreover, why does the author chooses not to talk about the $U(2)$ group? Does he skips over it as it is not useful, or is there a mathematical reason for which $U(2)$ cannot be taken into consideration?

P.S.: Thank you in advance for any of your eventual answers, and excuse my poor English: I'm still learning it!

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: I tried removing the part of the question which was not essential. Is it okay now? (even if there is still more than one question left I think that the remaining one concern the same thing)

Comment: No reason to exclude $SU(1)$ and $U(2).$ Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_group and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group

Comment: what is the difference between $SU(1)$ and $U(1)$, then?

Comment: Yes, that's better. Thank you.

Comment: $SU(1)=\{1\}\subsetneq$[U(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_group).

Comment: Treating $1\times1$ matrices as scalars, $SU(1)=\{1\}$ is trivial, while $U(1)=S^1$ is the unit circle in the complex plane. The unit quaternions correspond to $SU(2)$, not $U(2)$. That's not to say there aren't contexts where $U(2)$ is relevant, this just isn't such a context.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer!

Comment: @runway44 Do you want to turn your comment into an answer?